# push for loop result as array laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel-5

I know this easy but I still can't solve it, I have this piece of code :

```
$names = [
    '1' => 'name1',
    '2' => 'name2',
    '3' => 'name3',
];
```

It's simple for small number array, but how if i get many data and always change?, I plan to use for loop

```
$totaldata = 5    

for($z=1; $z<=$totaldata; $z++) {
    $yz = name.$z;

    $names = [
        $z => $yz,
    ];
}
```

but somehow it doesn't work, any solution?

Comment: how to loop that 1 => name1 ... and so on inside array, say if there are 100 data and change every minutes it really are impossible to change it and add new data manually every minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not add new data to `$names` array, you just overwrite it all the time.

So change this code:

```
$names = [
        $z => $yz,
    ];
```

to this:

```
$names[$z] = $yz;
```

It is also a good point to initialize `$names` before loop. So the result should be like this:

```
$totaldata = 5    
$names = [];

for($z=1; $z<=$totaldata; $z++) {
    $yz = name.$z;

    $names[$z] = $yz;
}
```